# Condense array with empty values php

Tags: php, arrays

I originally have an array that reads

```
$array1 = array("a","a","b","b")
```

I run it through 'array_unique', but I want it to only have two elements.  Basically, I want to eliminate empty elements and reduce the keys, i.e.

```
[0]=>string(1) "a"
```

and

```
[1]=>string(1) "b"
```

I'm stuck.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: That's what `array_unique` already does. What is the problem exactly? Do you actually *use* the return value, as in `$arr = array_unique($arr)`?

Comment: When I var_dump array_unique(array1), I get [0]=>string(1) "a" and [2]=>string(1) "b".  I want [0]=>string(1) "a" and [1]=>string(1) "b"

Comment: I guess my question is what is the best way to change a set of keys to start at zero and increment by one, while keeping values in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_unique()` is what you would use, as you mentioned.

If you want the keys to be reset, use `array_values()`.

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/JpiHDwOZ).

Comment: I guess my question is what is the best way to change a set of keys to start at zero and increment by one, while keeping values in the array?